# How can I make a java file compile on save or run in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation

I'm pretty new to Java and vscode so bear with me.

In my Java project I have several .java files. When I run App.java the first time, .class files are generated from all the .java files as expected. If I make a change to one of the files (other than App.java) and save it, it is not recompiled when I run App.java unless I delete its .class file. The only other options I am aware of are to compile it manually or run it even though it doesn't have a main function, but is there a way to compile it automatically when it is saved or when App.java is run?

EDIT -
At first the files were in a regular folder, but then I created a Java project and moved all the files into it. On the first run, .class files were created in both the bin folder and in the src folder. The same issue is exists even in the Java project. Deleting the files in the bin folder seems to make no difference, and deleting the .class files in the src folder requires manual recompiling before running

EDIT 2 -
To clarify:
Current behaviour - Run App.java, all .java files are compiled, it works.
Make changes to a file and save, run App.java, only App.java is compiled and changes are not displayed.

Desired behaviour - Run App.java, all .java files are compiled, it works.
Make changes to a file and save, run App.java, all .java files are compiled and changes are displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer to the documentation [Getting Started with Java in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken I did but I can’t find anything about it. Maybe I’m not looking in the right place?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue in VS Code with java files. can you post a small example that produces the issue for you that I can test and observe the problem that you are experiencing ?

Comment: Are you opening a project or a folder containing just a few Java scripts? If it is just an ordinary Java script, when compiling and running one of them, the remaining scripts in the folder will not be compiled.

Comment: @JialeDu initially it was just a folder but then I created a Java project and moved all the .java files into the src folder. Compiled .class files go into both the bin folder and alongside the .java files in the src folder

Comment: Isn't that normal behavior? What's the problem? If I'm misunderstanding you.Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu As I said, I'm pretty new to both Java and vscode so I don't know if it's normal behaviour or not but it doesn't matter. My question is whether files can be compiled automatically when they are saved or when App.java is run. Maybe it should and my vscode is broken, or maybe I have to configure or install something. It doesn't matter how I just want to know if and how it can be done

Comment: For your expected behavior, if you only run the app, then of course it will only compile the app. this is the correct behavior. Your expected behavior used to happen before, but this has long been fixed as wrong behavior.

Comment: @JialeDu well that's disappointing because it's mega annoying but thanks for helping anyway

Comment: Wouldn't this be normal behavior if they were unrelated several java scripts? There isn't any problem with it. If your post has been answered, please consider answering it yourself or closing the thread.

Comment: I didn’t say there’s a problem with it or it’s abnormal. The question is if there is a way to achieve what I want, not whether it is normal.